# TCL - find a regular pattern in a file and return the occurrence and number of occurrences

Tags: tcl

I am writing a code to grep a `regular expression` pattern from a file, and output that regular expression and the number of times it has occured.

Here is the code: I am trying to find the pattern "grep" in my file hello.txt:

```
set file1 [open "hello.txt" r]
set file2 [read $file1]
regexp {grep} $file2 matched
puts $matched
while {[eof $file2] != 1} {
set number 0
if {[regexp {grep} $file2 matched] >= 0} {
 incr number
}

puts $number
}
```

Output that I got:

```
grep

--------
can not find channel named "qwerty
iiiiiii
wxseddtt
lsakdfhaiowehf'
jbsdcfiweg
kajsbndimm s
grep
afnQWFH
 ACV;SKDJNCV;
    qw  qde 
 kI UQWG
grep
grep"
    while executing
"eof $file2"
```

Answer (score 5):

It's usually a mistake to check for `eof` in a while loop -- check the return code from `gets` instead:

```
set filename "hello.txt"
set pattern {grep}
set count 0

set fid [open $filename r]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    incr count [regexp -all -- $pattern $line]
}
close $fid

puts "$count occurrances of $pattern in $filename"
```

Another thought: if you're just counting pattern matches, assuming your file is not too large:

```
set fid [open $filename r]
set count [regexp -all -- $pattern [read $fid [file size $filename]]]
close $fid
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is caused by the command `eof $file2`. The reason is that `$file2` is not a *file handle* (resp. channel) but contains the content of the file `hello.txt` itself. You read this file content with `set file2 [read $file1]`.

If you want to do it like that I would suggest to rename `$file2` into something like `$filecontent` and loop over every contained line:

```
foreach line [split $filecontent "\n"] {
  ... do something ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Glenn is spot on. Here is another solution: Tcl comes with the fileutil package, which has the grep command:

```
package require fileutil
set pattern {grep}
set filename hello.txt
puts "[llength [fileutil::grep $pattern $filename]] occurrences found"
```

If you care about performance, go with Glenn's solution.

Comment: +1, but I think you mean TclLib or ActiveTcl comes with fileutil -- it's not a core package

Comment: @Glenn: My mistake, yes fileutil is part of tcllib.